# Draw Venn diagram for this situation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

This year 120 students receive gold star, 180 students receive certificates and 80 students receive blue ribbon. Of these, 40 students receive gold star with no other award, 50 students receive certificates with no other reward and 10 students receive blue ribbons with no other rewards. In addition, 10 students receive all awards and 65 students receive no awards. Draw the Venn diagram to represent this situation and determine how many students attend the schools this year.

Comment: Start by entering the value in the innermost region (10 students receive all three awards) and work outwards

Comment: How to draw the table?

Comment: Had a look and have to admit a table isn't a great idea after all.  Sorry, i misread the problem.  Venn diagram is better.

Comment: I draw out the Venn diagram and it seem to have problem!

Comment: I got 305 students attending the year.  I let the number of students with Gold and a Ribbon be $a$ I worked out Gold and Certified in terms of $a$ and hence Certified and Ribbon in terms of $a$  I found $a=0$

Comment: no understand with the explanation, can you post the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my Venn diagram:

[image]

I let $a$ be the number of Gold and Ribbon.

In doing so I worked out there must be $(70-a)$ Gold and Cert and $(60-a)$ Ribbon and Cert.

I solved the equation $70-a+60-a+10+50=180$ to get $a=5$

Does this help?

Comment: from the equation, isn't a = 5?

Comment: anyway, thank for your guidance. My calculated answer is 300. Thank

Comment: You are right.  Sorry for everything mistakes along the way.

Comment: Never mind. Thank a lot!